# Ruby convert 1d array to 2d inline

Tags: arrays, ruby

Solving the 11th problem at the Project Euler I got myself stuck with the input.

"08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48"

I need to convert this 1d array into a 2d array ( 20×20 ). How can I do this inline?

Comment: Your question is unclear. [tag:Ruby] doesn't have a concept of [tag:inline] functions. And Ruby doesn't have 2D [tag:arrays].

Comment: You can use `array.each_slice(20).to_a` to put each 20 elements into a subarray.

Answer (score 3):

Let's convert a string to a 25-element array, `a`, by splitting on whitespace, and then convert `a` to a 5-element array, `b`, whose elements are 5-element arrays, such that `b[i][j] = a[5*i+j]`<sup>1</sup>.

Suppose<sup>2</sup>

```
str = 
"08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00
75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17"
```

Then

```
arr = str.split
  #=> ["08", "02", "22", "97", "38", "15", "00", "40", "00", "75", "04", "05", "07",
  #    "78", "52", "12", "50", "77", "91", "08", "49", "49", "99", "40", "17"]
arr.size
  #=> 25

arr.each_slice(5).to_a
  #=> [["08", "02", "22", "97", "38"],
  #    ["15", "00", "40", "00", "75"],
  #    ["04", "05", "07", "78", "52"],
  #    ["12", "50", "77", "91", "08"],
  #    ["49", "49", "99", "40", "17"]]
```

If you want integer values,

```
arr.map(&:to_i).each_slice(5).to_a
  #=> [[ 8,  2, 22, 97, 38],
  #    [15,  0, 40,  0, 75],
  #    [ 4,  5,  7, 78, 52],
  #    [12, 50, 77, 91,  8],
  #    [49, 49, 99, 40, 17]]
```

Putting this together, we can substitute out the variable `arr` and write:

```
str.split.map(&:to_i).each_slice(5).to_a
```

See [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split), [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-to_i), [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) and the definition of [whitespace](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ruby-cookbook/0596523696/ch01s11.html).

<sup>1. In Ruby-speak, "An array of 5 elements, each a 5-element array" might be called a "5x5 array" in some other languages. We can, however, refer to a "5x5 matrix`. See [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html).</sup>

<sup>2. I have adopted the asker's presentation of the string, which has only 13 lines of varying length. See my comment on @steenslag's answer</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the Project Euler string and past it between the quotes, newlines and all:

```
str = ""
```

First we need the lines in an array. That is easy:

```
ar = str.lines
```

Now we have an array of 20 strings; some work to do. Adjust the previous line with:

```
ar = str.lines.map{|line| line.split}
```

Which results in an array of 20 arrays, all containing 20 strings. Don't want strings, want integers. So adjusting again:

```
ar = str.lines.map{|line| line.split.map{|str| str.to_i }}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted. Helped me a lot.

Comment: Readers: [Project Euler #11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11) is generally cast in terms of a 20x20 "grid", which I suppose could be an array of 20 elements, each element an array of 20 integers, or a string having 20 lines, as steenslag has assumed. The question is misleading on that score as it presents a string with 13 lines, each containing 31 two-digit strings, except for the last line, which contains 28 two-digit strings: `12*31 + 28 #=> 400`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to Project Euler #11. The problem is to determine the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid.

I will use four helper methods, illustrating the behaviour of each with the array

```
arr = [[ 1,  2,  3, 4,],
       [12, 13, 14, 5,],
       [11, 16, 15, 6,],
       [10,  9,  8, 7,]]
```

and the number of elements for which the product is to be maximized

```
n = 3
```

```
def max_product_in_vector(v, n)
  v.each_cons(n).map { |a| a.reduce(:*) }.max
end

max_product_in_vector(arr[0], n)
  #=> 24 (2x3x4)
```

```
def max_product_in_array(a, n)
  a.map { |row| max_product_in_vector(row, n) }.max
end

max_product_in_array(arr, n)           # rows
  #=> 2640 (11*16*15)

max_product_in_array(arr.transpose, n) # columns
  #=> 1872 (13*16*9)
```

```
def off_diagonals(arr, n)
  indices = arr.each_index.to_a
  indices.product(indices).
          group_by { |i,j| i+j }.
          values.
          reject { |a| a.size < n }.
          map { |a| a.map { |i,j| arr[i][j] } }
end

off_diagonals(arr, n)
  #=> [[3, 13, 11], [4, 14, 16, 10], [5, 15, 9]]

max_product_in_array(off_diagonals(arr, n), n)
  #=> 2240 (14*16*10)
```

```
def rotate_anticlockwise(arr)
  arr.map(&:reverse).transpose
end

r = rotate_anticlockwise(arr)
  #=> [[4, 5, 6, 7],
  #    [3, 14, 15, 8],
  #    [2, 13, 16, 9],
  #    [1, 12, 11, 10]] 

off_diagonals(r, n)
  #=> [[6, 14, 2], [7, 15, 13, 1], [8, 16, 12]] 

max_product_in_array(off_diagonals(r, n), n)
  #=> 1536 (7*15*13)
```

We are given

```
str = 
"08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
 49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
 81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
 52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
 22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
 24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
 32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
 67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
 24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
 21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
 78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
 16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
 86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
 19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
 04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
 88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
 04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
 20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
 20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
 01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48"
```

The maximum product of four consecutive elements in rows, columns, diagonals and off-diagonals is obtained as follows.

```
n = 4
arr = str.split.map(&:to_i).each_slice(20).to_a
  #=> [[ 8,  2, 22,..., 91,  8],
  #    [49, 49, 99,..., 62,  0],
  # ...
  #    [ 1, 70, 54,..., 67, 48]]

[max_product_in_array(arr, n),                                       # rows
 max_product_in_array(arr.transpose, n),                             # columns
 max_product_in_array(off_diagonals(rotate_anticlockwise(arr),n),n), # diagonals
 max_product_in_array(off_diagonals(arr,n),n)                        # off-diagonals
].max  
   #=> 70600674 (89*94*97*87, on off-diagonal, arr[12][6] to arr[15][3]
```

Without `.max` at the end the above expression returns

```
[48477312, # rows
 51267216, # columns
 40304286, # diagonals
 70600674] # off-diagonals
```